# How to store byte[] in mssql column varbinary(max) without encoding data with base64

Tags: sql-server, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-rest

I have a byte[] in my entity which i am storing in mssql table in a
column whose data type is varbinary(max).Now the value of the array
before storing it in db is different from the value retrieved after
storing it in database. I dont want to convert the byte[] to base64
and then save it in db and then decode it.Also i am using spring
data jpa. Can anybody suggest a solution for the same.

```
@Entity @Table(name="xyz",schema="lmn") 
public class PasswordResetToken {    
    private static final int EXPIRATION = 60 * 24;

    @Id     
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)     
    @Column(name="ID")  
    private Long id;

    @Lob    
    @Column(name="TOKEN")   
    private byte[] token;

    @OneToOne(targetEntity = UserDto.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false, name = "USERID")  
    private UserDto userDto;

    @Column(name="EXPIRYDATE")  
    private Date expiryDate; 
}
```

Comment: Your code is completely fine, how do you comparing values before and after storing?

Comment: Just tested on H2 with or without @Lob - all works fine.